# Simulating a badge on a UISegmentedControl that is being used as a navigation item

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uisegmentedcontrol, badge

I have a `UIViewController` that is embedded in a `UINavigationController`.  The navigation item for this view controller is a `UISegmentedControl` with 3 segments.  I'm trying to find a way to add a "new" badge to each of the segments.  It appears that `UISegmentedControl` does not normally allow you to do this but I was thinking that for my purposes, perhaps I could simulate this using a custom `UIView` positioned at the left or right edge of each segment.  I know I can get the width of the `UISegmentedControl` and since the auto-size mode is set to "equal widths", it seems reasonable that I could simply divide the total width by 3 to determine the approximate width of each segment.

However, there are a couple of things that I'm not sure about:

1. Is it possible to determine the x/y position of the `UISegmentedControl` within the navigation bar so I know where to position the custom view(s)?
2. Is it then possible to add a custom view at these positions inside the space contained by the navigation bar?

Comment: My guess would be creating a wrapper view around UISegmentedControl and rule all the logic from the view. It could basically be just a UIView with segmented control added in it as subview. Now by using your simple calculations you will easily find the positions of the segments, and also, since it's in your own UIView space, you can do whatever you want with adding your badges anywhere across this view.

Comment: In terms of user experience, that might "lead to a disconnected and confusing interface."

https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/controls/segmented-controls/

Answer (score 1):

Add Views above the Segment Control, put constraint.
[image]

In `ViewDidLoad()`  use the code

```
 self.badge1.addSubview(self.addCounter(count: 0))
 self.badge2.addSubview(self.addCounter(count: 9))
```

Use this function to make badge counter

```
func addCounter(count: Int)->UIView {
    // Count > 0, show count
    if count > 0 {

        // Create label
        let fontSize: CGFloat = 10
        let label = UILabel()
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: fontSize)
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.textColor = .white
        label.backgroundColor = .red

        // Add count to label and size to fit
        label.text = "\(NSNumber(value: count))"
        label.sizeToFit()

        // Adjust frame to be square for single digits or elliptical for numbers > 9
        var frame: CGRect = label.frame
        frame.size.height += CGFloat(Int(0.4 * fontSize))
        frame.size.width = (count <= 9) ? frame.size.height : frame.size.width + CGFloat(Int(fontSize))
        label.frame = frame

        // Set radius and clip to bounds
        label.layer.cornerRadius = frame.size.height / 2.0
        label.clipsToBounds = true

        // Show label in accessory view and remove disclosure
        return label

    } else {
        return UIView()
    }
}
```

And final result
[image]

Answer (score 0):

For those wanting to access the image views via the index, I created an extension, but it's not ideal, as it has to check whether the image data is equal, but works so far for me

```swift
extension UISegmentedControl {
    func getImageView(at index: Int) -> UIImageView? {
        guard let image = imageForSegment(at: index) else { return nil }
        let imageViews = subviews.compactMap { $0.subviews.first(where: { $0 is UIImageView }) as? UIImageView }
        return imageViews.first(where: {
            return $0.image?.isEqualTo(image: image) == true
        })
    }
}

extension UIImage {
    func isEqualTo(image: UIImage) -> Bool {
        guard let data1 = image.pngData() else { return false }
        guard let data2 = self.pngData() else { return false }

       return data1 == data2
    }
}
```